# Select first positive match per ID per date in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with different observations over time. As soon as an ID has a positive value for "Match", the rows with the ID in the dates that follow has to be removed. This is an example dataframe:

```
      Date  ID  Match
2018-06-06  5    1
2018-06-06  6    0
2018-06-07  5    1
2018-06-07  6    0
2018-06-07  7    1
2018-06-08  5    0
2018-06-08  6    1
2018-06-08  7    1
2018-06-08  8    1
```

Desired output:

```
      Date  ID  Match
2018-06-06  5    1
2018-06-06  6    0
2018-06-07  6    0
2018-06-07  7    1
2018-06-08  6    1
2018-06-08  8    1
```

In other words, because ID=5 has a positive match on 2018-06-06, the rows with ID=5 are removed for the following days BUT the row with the first positive match for this ID is kept.

Reproducable example:

```
Date <- c("2018-06-06","2018-06-06","2018-06-07","2018-06-07","2018-06-07","2018-06-08","2018-06-08","2018-06-08","2018-06-08")
ID <- c(5,6,5,6,7,5,6,7,8)
Match <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Date,ID,Match)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Fyi, you do not need `cbind` .. can just do `data.frame(Date, ID, Match)`. With `cbind`, a matrix is made, so all three columns become factors or strings.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Match := as.integer(as.character(Match))] # fix bad format

df[, .SD[shift(cumsum(Match), fill=0) == 0], by=ID]

   ID       Date Match
1:  5 2018-06-06     1
2:  6 2018-06-06     0
3:  6 2018-06-07     0
4:  6 2018-06-08     1
5:  7 2018-06-07     1
6:  8 2018-06-08     1
```

We want to drop rows after the first Match == 1.

`cumsum` takes the cumulative sum of Match. It is zero until the first Match == 1. We want to keep the latter row and so check `cumsum` on the preceding row with `shift`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative approach, where we spot the minimum row number where `Match` = 1 (i.e. first row with positive match) for each `ID` and we filter on that:

```
Date <- c("2018-06-06","2018-06-06","2018-06-07","2018-06-07","2018-06-07","2018-06-08","2018-06-08","2018-06-08","2018-06-08")
ID <- c(5,6,5,6,7,5,6,7,8)
Match <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Date,ID,Match))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                                     # for each ID
  mutate(min_row = min(row_number()[Match == 1])) %>%  # get the first row where you have 1
  filter(row_number() <= min_row) %>%                  # keep previous rows and that row
  ungroup() %>%                                        # forget the grouping
  select(-min_row)                                     # remove unnecessary column

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Date       ID    Match
#   <fct>      <fct> <fct>
# 1 2018-06-06 5     1    
# 2 2018-06-06 6     0    
# 3 2018-06-07 6     0    
# 4 2018-06-07 7     1    
# 5 2018-06-08 6     1    
# 6 2018-06-08 8     1
```

You can run the code step by step to see how it works. I've created `min_row` column to help you understand. You can re-write the above as

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                                    
  filter(row_number() <= min(row_number()[Match == 1])) %>%                
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Frank answer's

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Flag = cumsum(as.numeric(Match))) %>%
        filter(Match==0 & Flag==0 | Match==1 & Flag==1)

 # A tibble: 6 x 4
 # Groups:   ID [4]
  Date       ID    Match  Flag
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 2018-06-06 5     1         1
2 2018-06-06 6     0         0
3 2018-06-07 6     0         0
4 2018-06-07 7     1         1
5 2018-06-08 6     1         1
6 2018-06-08 8     1         1
```

## Data

```
Date <- c("2018-06-06","2018-06-06","2018-06-07","2018-06-07","2018-06-07","2018-06-08","2018-06-08","2018-06-08","2018-06-08")
ID <- c(5,6,5,6,7,5,6,7,8)
Match <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Date,ID,Match),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: This will break if the first 1 for a specific ID is followed by a 0 for that specific ID.

Comment: @AntoniosK you are correct, can you please check it now.

Comment: Yes, now it works (i.e. solves the issue I mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

I have another way to do it with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  # You can use order(Date) if you don't want to coerce Date into date object
  mutate(ord = order(Date), first_match = min(ord[Match > 0]), ind = seq_along(Date)) %>% 
  filter(ind <= first_match) %>%
  select(Date:Match)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
  Date          ID Match
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-06-06     5     1
2 2018-06-06     6     0
3 2018-06-07     6     0
4 2018-06-07     7     1
5 2018-06-08     6     1
6 2018-06-08     8     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)  
df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(first_match = min(Date[Match == 1])) %>% 
  filter((Match == 1 & Date == first_match) | (Match == 0 & Date < first_match)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-first_match)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Date       ID    Match
  <date>     <fct> <fct>
1 2018-06-06 5     1    
2 2018-06-06 6     0    
3 2018-06-07 6     0    
4 2018-06-07 7     1    
5 2018-06-08 6     1    
6 2018-06-08 8     1
```